# SqlDataSource ControlParameter Null Value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using SqlDataSource control to list out search result when user choose the date, if the date is null, then it list out all record.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  meta:resourcekey="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_ConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="select MeetingID, MeetName as MeetingName, MeetDate, MeetTime from Meeting where Status ='Recorded' and Case when @sel_to_date ='' then MeetDate <= '2200-12-31' else MeetDate = @sel_to_date end order by MeetDate desc, Meettime desc ">
<SelectParameters>                        
<asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" ControlID="datepicker" Name="sel_to_date" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But it return syntax error.

I want all to list all records when user leave the textbox blank. How to do that?

regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `case` statement is incorrect. The `case` statement in SQL should return a value, not perform a comparison. See [CASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

A solution would be to replace the `case` with a conditional like so:

```
select 
    MeetingID, MeetName as MeetingName, MeetDate, MeetTime 
from Meeting 
    where Status ='Recorded' 
    and 
    (
        (@sel_to_date ='' and MeetDate <= '2200-12-31' )
        or
        MeetDate = @sel_to_date
    )
order by MeetDate desc, Meettime desc
```

For your convenience, here it is on a single line so you can copy-paste it into the data source declaration:

```
select MeetingID, MeetName as MeetingName, MeetDate, MeetTime from Meeting where Status ='Recorded' and ((@sel_to_date ='' and MeetDate <= '2200-12-31' ) or MeetDate = @sel_to_date) order by MeetDate desc, Meettime desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  meta:resourcekey="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_ConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="select MeetingID, MeetName as MeetingName, MeetDate, MeetTime from Meeting where Status ='Recorded' and Case when @sel_to_date is null then MeetDate <= '2200-12-31' else MeetDate = @sel_to_date end order by MeetDate desc, Meettime desc ">
<SelectParameters>                        
<asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" ControlID="datepicker" Name="sel_to_date" DefaultValue="" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I did not check it but if you pass empty value than it convert to null so you have to check 
@sel_to_date is null instead @sel_to_date = ''
use my snippet of code.